# Set background image to each ListBox ItemsPanel in WP7.1

Tags: wpf, windows-phone-7, windows-phone-8, silverlight-toolkit

Hi i am new in windows mobile development.

I need to Set background image to each ListBox ItemsPanel.

```
<Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot" Background="Transparent">
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>

        <!--TitlePanel contains the name of the application and page title-->
        <StackPanel x:Name="TitlePanel" Grid.Row="0" Margin="12,17,0,28">
            <TextBlock x:Name="ApplicationTitle" Text="Issues" Style="{StaticResource PhoneTextNormalStyle}"/>
        </StackPanel>

        <!--ContentPanel - place additional content here-->
        <Grid x:Name="ContentPanel" Grid.Row="1" Margin="12,0,12,0">
            <rlb:PullDownToRefreshPanel
            x:Name="refreshPanel"
            RefreshRequested="refreshPanel_RefreshRequested"
            Grid.Row="2" />

            <rlb:ReorderListBox FlowDirection="LeftToRight" 
            x:Name="allIssuesItemsListBox" 
            ItemsSource="{Binding All_xp_issue}" 
            Margin="12, 0, 12, 0"  
            ItemTemplate="{StaticResource IssuesItemTemplate}" 
            SelectionChanged="allIssuesItemsListBox_SelectionChanged"
            IsReorderEnabled="{Binding IsChecked, ElementName=enableReorderCheckbox}"
             >
                <ListBox.ItemsPanel>
                    <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                        <toolkit:WrapPanel HorizontalAlignment="Center">
                        </toolkit:WrapPanel>
                    </ItemsPanelTemplate>
                </ListBox.ItemsPanel>
            </rlb:ReorderListBox>
        </Grid>
    </Grid>
```

Till now i designed page in which items are warped using toolkit:WrapPanel.

Now for each panel i want to set an background image. Means if there are two items in one panel than for both items i want to set one background image.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You can set background of toolkit:WrapPanel with an image brush

create a image brush in resources.

```
<ImageBrush ImageSource="/images/YourImage.jpg" x:Key="BackgroundBrush" />
```

Use the imagebrush as  toolkit:WrapPanel background

```
<toolkit:WrapPanel  Background="{DynamicResource BackgroundBrush}"></toolkit:WrapPanel>
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply. But i am not able to use DynamicResource  in my project. It is giving me "Type DynamicResource was not found" error. I am using "VS2010 express for windows phone" for development.

Comment: Yes i have tried staticresource but i am getting only one background image which is for all the items in the listbox. I want to set background image for each warped items.

Comment: In that case you have to set "BackgroundBrush" as background for the content in the ItemTemplate which is "IssuesItemTemplate".